# * bash: ./file.sh: Permission denied*

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to run `./file.sh` ,it is located in another volume `python file.py` is working correctly  but `./file.sh` is not. i have also tried `chmod u+x` . please help !!!

Comment: What's in the `mount` output? Is the problem volume mounted `noexec`?

Comment: Another idea: what's the hashbang line at the top of file.sh, i.e. `#!/bin/bash` or similar? Is it valid?